# "更进一步，不知道该如何做" equals "But further, I have no idea to do it"?

Tags: translation

I translate `"But further, I have no idea to do it"` to "更进一步，不知道该如何做"?
Is it normal ?

Comment: I would use 下一步。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, some more context would be good.

更进一步，不知道该如何做。
*One more step, I not know should how do.

Depending on the context, you can translate your sentence variously as:

更进一步，不知道该如何做。
I don't know how to carry on.
I don't know what's next.
I don't know what I should do next.

Comment: thanks, this's more natural

Answer (score 1):

> *I translate "But further, I have no idea to do it" to "更进一步，不知道该如何做"? Is it normal?*

You forgot to take 进 (advance) into consideration

As a verb phrase, 更进一步 means "to advance (one step) further"

"**更进一步，不知道该如何做**" can be translated as "**To advance further, I don't how I should do it**" ([Topic + comment] sentence)

or  *"I don't know how I should do it to advance further"* ([SVO] sentence)